# Wordpress remove_cap() having no effect

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a WP theme that has a custom post type of 'Vehicle' and a custom user role of 'Seller'.

I am trying to remove the publish vehicle capability for users of the seller role and only allow them to 'Submit for review'** - I have been reading up a lot on this and I tried a plug in called 'WP Role Editor' but this did not work.

I also tried putting this code into my functions file but this is still having no effect whatsoever.

```
$role = get_role('seller'); 
$role->remove_cap('publish_posts', false);
```

Is there a way around this, I have tried a few different code snippets from various websites but none of them seem to do the trick. Your input will be greatly appreciated.

Information when doing var_dump($role)

```
object(WP_Role)#464 (2) { 
    ["name"]= string(6) "seller" 
        ["capabilities"]= array(20) { 
        ["read"]= bool(true)
        ["upload_files"]= bool(true) 
        ["assign_seek_terms"]= bool(true)
        ["create_product"]= bool(true) 
        ["edit_post"]= bool(true)
        ["edit_gallery_group_post"]= bool(true)
        ["edit_download_group_post"]= bool(true) 
        ["edit_seek_post"] = bool(false) 
        ["read_seek_post"]= bool(false) 
        ["delete_seek_post"] = bool(false) 
        ["edit_seek_posts"] = bool(true)
        ["edit_others_seek_posts"] = bool(false) 
        ["publish_seek_posts"] = bool(true) 
        ["read_private_seek_posts"] = bool(false)
        ["delete_seek_posts"] = bool(true) 
        ["delete_private_seek_posts"] = bool(false) 
        ["delete_published_seek_posts"] = bool(true)
        ["delete_others_seek_posts"] = bool(false) 
        ["edit_private_seek_posts"]= bool(false)
        ["edit_published_seek_posts"]= bool(true) 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Looking at your var_dump data, 'seller' doesn't have 'publish_posts' to begin with and therefore it cannot be removed!

Comment: Thanks for your input Max, unfortunately this is giving the same result (or lack of result)

Comment: What information do you get when you `var_dump($role)`, also there is the alternative syntax of `global $wp_roles; $wp_roles->remove_cap('seller', 'publish_posts');`

Comment: I have added this into the question, does this help?

Comment: Doesn't look like 'seller' has 'publish_posts' to begin with?

Comment: Ah, found the answer, I had to do $role->remove_cap('publish_seek_posts'); Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I would look into capabilities for the custom post type see section on capabilities here [https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type]

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
global $wp_roles;
$wp_roles->remove_cap( 'seller', 'publish_posts' );
```